# How to generate this kind of waveform from audio in python?

Tags: python, audio

[image]

Hi,

How should I go about generating a waveform like this in python? I do not need the code. Steps to generate these would be enough.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate the height of the bars or how to generate the image itself?

Comment: @DavidZwicker, latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Subdivide the waveform according to the scale. For example, if the waveform is 1 second long and you want are planning to display 10 bars then divide into 100ms chunks. Each 100ms chunk would be a certain number of samples depending on the sample rate. A 48kHz sample rate has 48000 samples per second so 100ms is 4800 samples.
2. Enumerate each chunk of samples and compute the minimum and maximum values.
3. Scale and translate the minimum and maximum values to obtain the desired screen y-coordinates for the box you wish to draw.

An alternative for #2 is to compute the abs(max(samples)) for each chunk and then use the positive and negative of that for the min and max. This makes it always symmetrical.

Comment: Thank for the answer, I've posted a solution for future references.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Github Project check it out,
https://github.com/andrewrk/waveform 
 It's written in c and js. You can check the code review and implement it in your own language. 
  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jaket for the great answer.

I've written the code and posted here. https://gist.github.com/moeseth/130cd92dc47c56c47030

You will need pydub, matplotlib, numpy and PIL libraries